# When opening a directory with vim, why does attempting to select text with the mouse gives the error "E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off"?

Tags: vim, textselection, netrw

If I run `evim foo`, where foo is a directory, I get a buffer that looks something like

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v156)
"   /home/chris-henry/foo
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:special
" ==============================================================================
../
./
bar/
baz/
qux
```

I can select text by using `Shift` + arrow keys (or in other, more modeful ways, I presume), but trying to select text with the mouse gives the error:

```
E21: "Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off"
```

But I wasn't trying to make changes; I was just trying to select text (in order to middle-click paste it elsewhere). And `vim` (or netrw?) clearly has no problems with my selecting text, since I can do it with `Shift` + arrow keys. So why is click-and-drag a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I understand this…

- `:help netrw-cr` maps `<CR>` to enter the directory/file on the current line.
- `:help netrw-leftmouse` emulates a `<CR>`.
- You are using "easy Vim" so you are in insert mode by default.
- In insert mode, `<CR>` inserts a character so it changes the content of the buffer.
- You are in a "readonly" buffer, where changes to the content of the buffer are prohibited.
- Therefore you get an error because Vim thinks you are trying to change the content of the buffer.

Which is rather unfortunate.

I don't remember ever trying to disable or alter a Netrw mapping. Maybe you can find something in the very dense `:help netrw`.